# Difficulty uninstalling software

Tags: uninstall

I am trying to uninstall an app (Forticlient) with this command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove forticlient
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

I tried *killall* on the Forticlient processes but the error still occurs.

Is there a way to see which process is locking the file?

Alternatively is it possible to force the uninstallation even if there is a lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for and kill all apt processes:

```
ps aux | grep -i apt
sudo kill -9 <process id>
```

you can also type

```
sudo killall -s9 apt apt-get
```